# Get module ID in default.php file

Tags: joomla, module, joomla1.5

Hey guys how is it going!

I am trying check the running module ID in the default.php file. I need to get the module ID and go from there. I have read that $module->id should store that number in that file but I don't know why it does not print anything when I access it.

What else can I do? Do I have any option to solve my problem? I am dealing with Joomla 1.5.3
Really really need to get this done ASAP, give me a hand with this one please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the class and method to access a module id and other useful info about a module:

http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule

Comment: Definitely Joomla 1.5.3, seriously? If so, you are 23 version behind - current 1.5 latest is 1.5.26 - do you mean 2.5.3 a mere one version behind current 2.5 latest ?

Comment: Your link is outdate and returns a 404